# Maximum Likelihood Estimation in R for Extended dsitribution

Tags: r, distributions, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to estimate the four parameters(theta1, theta2, lambda, p) distribution using MLE with the choice of parameters (theta2 = 1, p = 1).

I have given my log likelihood function below.

```
n*log(p*theta1*theta2) + (theta1-1)*sum(log(ppois(x, lambda)))+
          (theta2-1)*sum(log(1-ppois(x,lambda)^theta1))+sum(log(dpois(x,lambda)))-
              2*sum(log(1-(1-p)*(1-ppois(x,lambda)^theta1)^theta2))
```

The following are the R codes I have written. But it give an errors. I would really appreciate if give any suggestion in this regard. Thanks.

```
theta2 <- 1
p <- 1
x <- seq(-0.01, 5, 0.01)
pfun <- function(lambda, theta1){
  n <-200  
  y <- x - n*log(p*theta1*theta2) + (theta1-1)*sum(log(ppois(x, lambda)))+
          (theta2-1)*sum(log(1-ppois(x,lambda)^theta1))+sum(log(dpois(x,lambda)))-
              2*sum(log(1-(1-p)*(1-ppois(x,lambda)^theta1)^theta2))
}
  est1<-mle(pfun, start = list(lambda = 2, theta2 = 1))

  summary(est1)
```